# Flask routing error using Blueprints in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: web, flask, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, werkzeug

I'll try to explain my problem the best that I can. I have a Flask app using blueprints with subdomains for redirecting to versions of the same site with different languages.

es.my_site -> spanish version.
en.my_site -> english version. and so on.

The app is working locally, defining:
`application.config['SERVER_NAME'] = my_site.com:5000` in application.py
and adding `127.0.0.1 my_site.com:5000`, `127.0.0.1 en.my_site.com:5000` and `127.0.0.1 es.my_site.com:5000` to /etc/hosts.

My problem starts when trying to deploy the app to aws beanstalk.
My first question is what to config in `application.config['SERVER_NAME']`, I've tried configuring the url that beanstalk gives me `my_site-env.eba-******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:5000`, and this works, but only for routes that don't use blueprints.
When I try to access an url generated by the blueprint, the `url_for()` method is called multiple times until an error is thrown, each time adding the subdomain again to the url.

`url_for()` is called multiple times and `redirect(url_for('endpoint'))` never redirects to the correct endpoint.

Result of each successive call to url_for():

```
es.my_site-env.eba-******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com  
es.es.my_site-env.eba-******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com  
es.es.es.my_site-env.eba-******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com  
es.es.es.es.my_site-env.eba-******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com  
es.es.es.es.es.my_site-env.eba-******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

This works fine locally, that's why I think this is related to a configuration in the Beanstalk server, my app configuration or something DNS related. But I'm not an expert in either Flask or AWS, so it could be something else.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.